# How to use cache manager for multiple users in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I want to performance test a web application. My scenario is to take the metrics for multiple users (say 10) with cache. So i have added HTTP cache manager, but cache work per individual users. Is there any way to cache the files once and use it for 'n' number of users in jmeter. Even i tried to put cache manager outside thread group but it dint work.

It should work like cache the files once and use the cache for all the threads in jmeter. Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Cache is per user/thread, see [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) doc:

> Each Virtual User thread has its own Cache

So you can execute with multiple users/threads as 10, just define `Number of Threads` in Thread Group and each will save different cache

Comment: Is there any way to make it global and use it for all users ?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 Thread Groups for your 2 groups of users:

- Put a [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) in the one that simulates users with cache
- Don't put a [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) in the one that simulates users without cache

Of course Http Cache Manager will only have effect in the second iteration of the Thread

Example:

[image: Sample plan]

Comment: Only one user should execute without cache and all other users should use cache

Comment: So do what i say, put 1 for first Thread Group and as much as you want for other one

Comment: It's behaving like every users are having their own cache.

Comment: Thanks for the response @ubik.